# Show/Hide button based on it's previous state with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to show a button when the user check/uncheck the checkbox. The checkbox can appear checked or unchecked for different users. How can I show/hide a button based on the previous state of the checkbox.
my current code is below.

```
$('#receive-msg').on('click',function (){
var btnNoMsg = $('#btn-no-msgs');
   btnNoMsg.removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
   btnNoMsg.removeClass('hide');
});
```

I know that I have to store the current state of the checkbox somewhere, and when is clicked again compare the previous state with the current state and show/hide the button.

**UPDATE:**
I have solved it using the following code.

```
 var btnNoMsg = $('#btn-no-msgs');
    var state = $(this).prop('checked');
    var receive = $(this).data('receive');
    var status = receive ? true : false;
    if (state === status){
        btnNoMsg.removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
    }else{
         btnNoMsg.removeClass('hide');
    }
```

But I'm going to use the code provided by `beautifulocoder`.

Comment: What is purpose of `btnNoMsg.removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: I have a wonderful solution for you. Give me a sec to write it up.

Comment: @guest271314 I forgot to remove that code, please ignore.

Comment: Ever heard of cookies?

Comment: Yes, but i think i can achieve this by using custom `data-*` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `toggleClass`:

```
$('#receive-msg').on('click', function () {
    $('#btn-no-msgs').toggleClass('hide');
});
```